# Pure java implementation of the java.lang.Math class

Tags: math, native, java

I just downloaded the openjdk source and came to the realization that nearly all of the java.lang.Math class was implemented in native c/c++ code. I was wondering if there were any implementations that were fully written in java.

Comment: I'm working on a project that converts the bytecodes generated by the java compiler to another form. To test the improvement that the conversion makes we have a series of tests. Many of my tests use the java.lang.Math class.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [MicroFloat](http://www.dclausen.net/projects/microfloat/). It targets J2ME platform and according to the author it implements all methods in java.lang.Math.

Answer (score 2):

Currently some pure Java improvements for methods in the `java.lang.Math` class are integrated into apache commons-math:

See: [Elementary functions in JDK are slower than necessary and not as accurate as they could be.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-375?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)